# Maven build release ${project.basedir}:unknown

Tags: java, maven

help me, please.

When I start a Perform Maven Release erro below appears:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.2.2:prepare (default-cli) on project JavaWeb: Cannot prepare the release because you have local modifications :
[ERROR] [${project.basedir}:unknown]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

My tags directory in SVN is empty.
Pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <tagBase>https://server01.com/svn/JavaWeb/tags/</tagBase>
        <tag>${project.artifactId}-${maven.build.timestamp}</tag>
        <preparationGoals>clean install</preparationGoals>
        <goals>package</goals>
        <arguments>-DskipTests=false</arguments>

        <providerImplementations>
            <svn>javasvn</svn>
        </providerImplementations>

        <checkModificationExcludes>
            <checkModificationExclude>${project.build.directory}</checkModificationExclude>
        </checkModificationExcludes>
    </configuration>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.maven-scm-provider-svnjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-svnjava</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

What's means that error? Is a problem in my repository?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using an old version of the maven-release-plugin (2.2.2) instead of 2.5 ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I changed maven-release-plugin to 2.5 but error continues.

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot prepare the release because you have local modifications : [ERROR] [${project.basedir}:unknown] [ERROR] -> [Help 1]

it means you have local code changes which needs to be checked in to your source control before you do release

Comment: it's probably worse: there's probably a file created in the project root, called `${project.basedir}`, because normally you would see the filename causing this problem.

Comment: `${project.basedir}` is not valid property, somehow it has reference to it http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/MavenPropertiesGuide

Comment: @Robert Scholte the stranger is my project is synchronized with repository

Comment: In this case, I need define a project.basedir in my pom.xml?

Comment: @Jigar It's valid, just not listed. To verify execute `mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.basedir` (indeed without ${}). @user3877552 I'd suggest to do a clean checkout first and try to release that. Then there should be no local modifications.

Comment: @Robert Scholte Thanks a lot. Fixed that problem. In Jenkins configuration, I changed Check-out Strategy Use 'svn update' as much as possible to Always check out a fresh copy.